# I need to separate the text from a string based on column names

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ocr

I am working on OCR based Android app, getting this text as string from the attached image dynamically (getting the text in Horizontal Direction from the image)

[image]

Text from Image:

"Part Name Part Cost Engine Oil and Oil Filter Replacement Rs 10K Alf Filter Rs 4500 Cabin AC Micro Filter Rs 4000 Pollen Filter Rs 1200 - 1500 AC Disinfectant Rs 3000 Fuel Filter Rs 6000 - 8000 Spark Plug Set Replacement (Applicable in TFSI / Petrol Car Range) Rs 10K Body Wash, Basic Clean 8. Engine Degrease Rs 3000 Body Wax Polish Detailed Rs 7000 - 8000 Car interior Dry Clean with Genn Clean Rs 8000 - 10000 Wheel Alignment \u0026 Balancing Rs 6000 - 7000 Brake Pads Replacernent (Pair) Rs 30K - 32K Brake Disc Replacernent (Pair) Rs 30K - 35K ..........".

I need to separate the Part Name and Part Cost(just 2 columns i.e Part Name, Part Cost) (ignore all extra text from the column heading). Separate the values from String and should store it in SQLIte Database Android. I am stuck how to get the values and separate them.

Comment: You could work on some column detection by summing the average colour of each vertical column, and then the same for horizontal rule-offs, and then apply your OCR to rectangular sub images within the space. You have a minor challenge that there are no vertical rule-offs, but your column detection should be able to cope with that - there will be a significant light to dark change at the start of the second column.

Answer (score 0):

The text returned from the OCR isn't ideal. The first thing you should do is check if whatever OCR solution can be configured to provide a better output. Ideally, you want the lines to be separated by newline characters and the space between the columns to be interpreted as something more useful, such as a tab character.

If you have no way of changing the text you get, you'll have to find some way of parsing it. You may want to look into using a parser, such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to make this easier.

The following observations may help you to come up with a parsing strategy:

- Column 2 items all start with "Rs" or "Upto Rs".
- Column 2 items end with:

  - A number (where a number is allowed to be a string of digits [0-9.], optionally followed by a "K"
  - "Lakh"
- Column 1 items don't begin with a number or "Lakh"

So a basic algorithm could be:

```
List<String> column1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> column2 = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] tokens = ocrString.split(" ");
List<String> column = column1;
String item = "";
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    String token = tokens[i];
    String nextToken = i == tokens.length - 1 ? "" : tokens[i+1];
    if (column == column1) {
        if (token == "Rs" || (token == "Upto" && nextToken == "Rs")) {
            column = column2;
            column.add(item); item = "";
            i--; continue;
        }
        item += " " + token;
    } else {
       item += " " + token;
       if (/*token is number or "Lakh" and nextToken is not*/) {
           column.add(item); item = "";
           column = column1;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response djd0.I didn't get algorithm.Can you please eloborate.

Comment: and also else if(/*token is number or "Lakh" and nextToken is not*/).Please explain djd0.